# Intercepting all Android Activity onCreate

Tags: java, android, byte-buddy

Been trying to hook up android with byte-buddy but having issues with my goal; That goal being to intercept onCreate, and then to add a Log.d(TAG, "Message")
to all Activities getting created.

*Updated with imports*

```
package he.herpa.autoloader;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion;
import net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperCall;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;
import net.bytebuddy.utility.RandomString;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class App extends Application {

private static final String TAG = "TEST";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

            ByteBuddy byteBuddy;
            byteBuddy = new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V6);

            try {
                File file = this.getDir(RandomString.make(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                    throw new IOException("Not a directory: " + file);
                }
                try {

                    byteBuddy
                            .redefine(Activity.class)
                            .method(ElementMatchers.named("onCreate"))
                            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Interceptor.class))
                            .make()
                            .load(Activity.class.getClassLoader(), new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy(file));

                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, e);
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.w(TAG, e);
            }

}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
}


public static class Interceptor {

    public static Void intercept(@SuperCall Callable<Void> zuper) throws Exception {
        Log.d("Test", "Should have placed a log in all onCreates");
        return zuper.call();
    }
}
```

First issue is that the class Activity does not seem to be found.

*Edit* `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate the class file for class he.herpa.autoloader.Activity using ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader`

Second issue is, am I even on the right track?

Comment: Why not [use `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)?

Comment: The Activity class isn't found? What do your import statements look like?

Comment: Because of injection needs

Comment: Please clarify why you need to inject code to something that already has a callback?

Comment: The goal is to move over the code to groovy and a gradle plugin
to initate automatic loading of company debuging tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte Buddy does not support redefinition or rebasement on Android. You can only do this during build time but the runtime for Android does not provide standardized access to Java byte code.